I can't detach from shared VPC because there is some dangling object I cannot find
I get this error:
 Error: Error disabling Shared VPC Resource "service-project-abc": Error waiting for Disabling Shared VPC Resource: The resource 'projects/service-project-abc/global/networkInstances/v-25513xxxxxab9cc9cf' is still linked to shared VPC host 'projects/host-project-abc'.

I was using cloud run and GKE.
I deleted the GKE cluster, cloud run instances, load balancers, IPs, and everything else I could find.
What is this thing? 'projects/service-project-abc/global/networkInstances/v-25513xxxxxab9cc9cf'
I see nothing under load balancers:

I can't delete the service project. Also, this makes me concerned that when deleting cloud run apps GCP leaves a bunch of garbage behind. How do I track this down?

While looking on the cloud logging for the specific error, try to follow this a guide for deprovisioning shared VPC that needs to be followed to avoid outages for your projects. If you're able to execute the guide and it still persists, I think you should ask help to support team.

I finally was able to solve this by disabling the Compute Engine and Serverless VPC API's in the project that was causing this message, although it is possible just disabling the Compute Engine one would have done the job.
